# How to include Variables in Localized Strings?

Tags: c#, string, localization, internationalization, globalization

I'm trying to display a message to the user along the lines of:

"User 5 could not be added"

But how can I add variables to a string that is being placed in a .resx file? I've trying searching for things like "Variables in Localization" "Globalization with Variables" etc, but came up dry.

If I weren't localizing I would write:

```
Console.Write("User " + userNum + " could not be added");
```

How can this be accomplished with resources?

Comment: You should not be constructing/printing string with + anyway. String.Format is so much easier to work with...

Comment: Better than String.Format in most cases:

```var myString = $"Put {myVariable} here.";```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In teams where I've done internationalization, we generally also created a resource for the format string, something like USER_COULD_NOT_BE_ADDED_FORMAT, and called String.Format (or your environment's equivalent) by passing that resource's value as the format pattern.

Then you'll do `Console.Write(String.Format(resourceManager.GetString("USER_COULD_NOT_BE_ADDED_FORMAT"), userNum));`

Most localizers either have training in the format strings used by the system they are localizing, or they are provided with guidance in the localization kit that you provide them. So this is not, for example, as high a barrier as making them modify code directly.

You generally need to add a loc comment to the resource ID to explain the positional parameters.

Comment: Could you just go a bit further into how I can add such a "loc comment to the resource ID"? Or provide me a link to read more? Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, while I have you here since you seem to have experience with these things, is it best to have a single resx file for all the strings in a given project, or would it be better to separate them into multiple resx files, say, one for each form? (My resx files themselves are stored in a separate Globalization project)

Comment: Assuming you're using the .resx format, the localization comment is just "Comment" in the resx editor UI, or `<comment>` in the xml right after the `<value>` element.

Comment: I recommend using multiple resx files, but more for source control sanity than anything else. Usually you create a packaged up .zip file (or similar) to send to localizers, and there shouldn't be any incremental cost for the flexibility of multiple files.

Comment: If one wants to do something similar, but when applying directly at a cshtml file, it can do it like this: @String.Format(@Localizer["USER_COULD_NOT_BE_ADDED_FORMAT"].Value, userNum)

Answer (score 16):

You can't do this directly.

What you *can* do is place a token - a specific string that can be *replaced* with `string.Replace` with the value of the variable.

A good candidate for this would be the built in string formatting:

```
Console.Write(string.Format("User {0} could not be added", userNum));
```

Assuming `userNum` has the value `5`, the result would be:

```
User 5 could not be added
```

You can localize this string with the composite format specifiers.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) like so:

```
Console.Write("User {0} could not be added", userNum);
```

This way you would localize `"User {0} could not be added"`.

Answer (score 4):

I would use string.Format

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

```
Console.Write(string.Format("User {0} could not be added", userNum));
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do that its simple
[image]

new lets see how

```
String.Format(Resource_en.PhoneNumberForEmployeeAlreadyExist,letterForm.EmployeeName[i])
```

this will gave me dynamic message every time

by the way I'm useing [ResXManager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68)